# Website URL does not redirect to Facebook Fan Page using Windows Smartphone

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink, windows-mobile, smartphone

I have a banner in my store that has a link that redirects to my Facebook Fan Page. It works ok using firefox, ie, chrome, etc.

But my boss noticed that can't access the Facebook fan page using Windows Mobile Smartphone.

My link is:https://www.facebook.com/pages/eshopsgr/207109759328396

Code:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/eshopsgr/207109759328396">fan page</a>`

It returns the 404 page of Magento...

Comment: What OS is running on your smartphone? There is normally no firefox or chrome for Windows Mobile OS.

Comment: I mention in the title that he uses windows OS. I have tried firefox, ie, chrome etc in a PC not a smartphone. He says that the link above in a windows smartphone does not work. returns 404. I don't have a windows smartphone to check it...

Comment: Possibly just the page is not reachable by the smartphone. Proyy or DNS problem. Can he/she open the main page: https://www.facebook.com?

Comment: hmm.. i'll have to question him.